# Checking if obj.prop1.prop2.prop3.prop4.prop5 value is null

Tags: c#, object, properties

If I have an obj and I want to get prop5 using `obj.prop1.prop2.prop3.prop4.prop5`, however, if  it is null, i am fine with returning a 'null'.

If obj.prop1.prop2 is null, it will throw an exception for prop3. So I have to have bunch of if-null statements for checking if anything is null for each property. Is there a quicker way out?

Tl;dr: Too many if statements, can I reduce them?

Current code, I just want to reduce this to something simpler (not bunch of if or and statements):

```
if(obj != null)
 if(obj.prop1 != null)
  if(obj.prop1.prop2 != null)
  .
  .
  .
     if(obj.pro1.prop2.prop3.prop4.prop5 ! = null)
         //do something
```

Comment: C# 6: `if(obj?.prop1?.prop2?.prop3 != null)`

Comment: thanks mate, ill try that. Honestly didn't know we can do that

Comment: It's called the [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).

Comment: You're violating [law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). Follow tell don't ask principle. You won't have this question at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using C# 6, this can be done in one conditional:

```
if(obj?.prop1?.prop2?.prop3 != null)
    // do something
```

Otherwise, you're stuck with the nesting of conditionals.  (Or a sequence of guard clauses instead of nested conditionals, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.)

Note that in many cases inspecting that deep into an object's properties might even be an indication of a design issue in the first place.  It's impossible to tell from the simplified example given, but you might make consuming code cleaner by encapsulating what you're looking for on the object itself.

For example, the class for `obj` might have this:

```
public SomeType SomeProperty()
{
    get
    {
        // nest your conditionals here, return null if the deeply nested value is null
    }
}
```

(Or maybe it's a method, or maybe the nested types also have such properties/methods, etc.  There are tons of ways to go about this.)

And in consuming code:

```
if (obj.SomeProperty != null)
    // do something
```

The point being that encapsulating the logic on the objects themselves makes the consuming code read much more cleanly and separates the variety of concerns regarding which objects are responsible for what.